# Adding support for p256 keys and signatures (secp256r1)

Tags: runtime, rust, extrinsic, oracles, ecdsa

Is it possible to add support for other cryptographic algorithms, or are we only allowed to use the implemented ones?

The implemented ones are sr25519, ed25519, ecdsa(secp256k1, not secp256r1).

I tried following this [oracle example](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs), but it seems to only wrap around sr25519. I then tried to mirror the [ecdsa implementation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/core/src/ecdsa.rs) but now I got to the point of trying to implement the [RuntimePublic trait](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/application-crypto/src/traits.rshttps://), but I see that for [other algorithms](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/application-crypto/src/ecdsa.rs), it is calling functions that talk to the [Keystore](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/keystore/src/lib.rs) through the [Crypto trait](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/io/src/lib.rs)

I finally saw that getting keys of a certain algorithm is hardcoded in the Keystore, and when getting all of the keys regardless of the algo used, it still [converts it](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/primitives/keystore/src/lib.rshttps://) into those 3 algorithms.

It seems that substrate only lets you define crypto types only as a renamed version of the same algorithm, and not create new ones on other elliptic curves for example. Is this the case?

Hardcoded crypto conversions of public keys from the Keystore:

```
impl SyncCryptoStore for LocalKeystore {
    fn keys(&self, id: KeyTypeId) -> std::result::Result<Vec<CryptoTypePublicPair>, TraitError> {
        let raw_keys = self.0.read().raw_public_keys(id)?;
        Ok(raw_keys.into_iter().fold(Vec::new(), |mut v, k| {
            v.push(CryptoTypePublicPair(sr25519::CRYPTO_ID, k.clone()));
            v.push(CryptoTypePublicPair(ed25519::CRYPTO_ID, k.clone()));
            v.push(CryptoTypePublicPair(ecdsa::CRYPTO_ID, k));
            v
        }))
    }
```

How an algorithm like secp256k1 retrieves from the Keystore:

```
...
        fn ecdsa_public_keys(&self, key_type: KeyTypeId) -> Vec<ecdsa::Public> {
            self.0
                .read()
                .raw_public_keys(key_type)
                .map(|v| {
                    v.into_iter()
                        .filter_map(|k| ecdsa::Public::from_slice(k.as_slice()).ok())
                        .collect()
                })
                .unwrap_or_default()
        }
    } // impl SyncCryptoStore for LocalKeystore
```

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that substrate only lets you define crypto types only as a renamed version of the same algorithm, and not create new ones on other elliptic curves for example. Is this the case?

Yes that is the case.

However, you can use [`insert_unknown`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4a19d408095ebcb47840ad1f2f086f53a0020cb7/client/keystore/src/local.rs#L311) to insert opaque private keys to the keystore and then use [`key_pair`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4a19d408095ebcb47840ad1f2f086f53a0020cb7/client/keystore/src/local.rs#L558) to get the private key. However, that will not work from the runtime.